# correctly use of number_format function to show converted values correctly to colombian peso

Tags: php

**calculate final price with discount and show converted their respective value in colombian pesos and dollars and use of function number_format**

> the proccess of dollar was successfully but arent correct the colombian peso showing value but before are converted from dollars to colombian peso (the calculated discount value are correct and showing correctly but not the final price showing correctly)

```
<!-- language: lang-php-->
//COUPON_TYPE = PERCENT_AMOUNT (%)
if($row1['coupon_type'] == 'percent_value'){
                                                
echo"DCTO = ". $DiscountedValueCOP = number_format($row['p_current_price'] * $row['ValorDolarUS'] * $row1['coupon_discount'] / 100); 
                                                              
$FinalPriceValueCOP = $DiscountedValueCOP - number_format($row['p_current_price'] * $row['ValorDolarUS']); 
                                                          
//FINAL PRICE MESSAGE FOR COLOMBIAN PESO...
    
echo "Final Price Of Product" . "<br>" . "With Discount Applied: " . "<br><br>" . "$" . number_format($FinalPriceValueCOP) . "<span> <i class='flag-icon flag-icon-col'> </i> COP</span>" . "<br><br>";
}else{
    
}
<!-- end snippet -->
```

I need this result please: (current price) = $18.272 COP (discount) = $3.753 COP = (final price) = $14.519 construction uniform

actually have this exactly value = $ - 15

Answer (score 0):

Set the number of decimal digits to 3 its by default 0 as second param `number_format` as follows:

```
$DiscountedValueCOP = number_format($row['p_current_price']* $row['ValorDolarUS']*$row1['coupon_discount']/100,3); 

//Final price should be current price - discount
$FinalPriceValueCOP = number_format($row['p_current_price']* $row['ValorDolarUS'],3) - $DiscountedValueCOP;
```

[more about `number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

number_format($FinalPriceValueCOP,3)

[please see this image here about the reazon of why minus symbol appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeRJR.png)

Comment: now the result its correct and i tried changed the price of product from database,but only works changing in the part of code where i show the value `number_format($FinalPriceValueCOP,3)` ... but this solution give me another problem.. now have the correct value..but the final result its correct but with symbol minus after $ price symbol and before price number,only i should just see $ price symbol and price in numbers.. i cant understand the origin of minus symbol